# Convert text to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I convert a text format e.g.

> Thursday, 1 January 2009

to a date in `sql`?

Thank you

Comment: What type of server are you using?

Comment: Check this, http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ hope it will be useful..but format which you have given will it be same always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(
     SUBSTRING('Thursday, 1 January 2009', 
       CHARINDEX(',', 'Thursday, 1 January 2009')+1, LEN('Thursday, 1 January 2009')) 
     AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: @Ocaso Protal I would like to group and sort data by Month and Year. i tried this but it doesn't work: ` select cast('1.'+ ( Month(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) +'.'+ Year(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) As DateTime) As Date ,* SUM(A) as A from CN_GA Group by Date order by Date ` Any suggestions?

Comment: @marylin Do you get any errors? You can't use an alias for your `Group By` so you have to repeat the complete `Cast...` Part in your `Group By`

Comment: I tried this:  select Geography, (Year(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME))+'/'+ Month(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) +'/1') ,Sum(Visits) as Visits,Sum("Goal1 Completions") as Bookings from CN_GA

Comment: Group by Geography, Year(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) , Month(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) Order by Geography,Year(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) , Month(CAST(SUBSTRING("day", CHARINDEX(',', "day")+1, LEN("day")) AS DATETIME)) But error show: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type int.

Comment: `Year` and `Month` return int values, so I fear you have to cast them too.

Comment: @marylin: BTW: Why do you store your dates as a varchar? Wouldn't it be better to store them as `datetime`?

Comment: @Ocaso Protal  the data i have to work on is in varchar. So with the Year and Month in separate columns, how do i cast them back such that i can display it with aggregated values when using group by function?

Comment: @marylin What do you mean with separate columns? `table.year` and `table.month`? Then you should be able to use `group by table.year+'.'+table.month` (untested, currently no SQL Server here)

Answer (score 1):

What type of text do you mean?
if you mean any type of text .... that isn't exist
if you mean text like '19900101' or like '1/1/2005' ... this will be converted to date automatic in sql server